# White gap appears in email template on Outlook 2010

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010, email-templates

I've used Mailchimp to build the main template structure and then modified properties and added some elements to get it working on Outlook versions.

It looks fine on most of web clients, desktop clients (Thunderbird and Mail[Apple]), but in Outlook, a white gap appears.

I've checked the code multiple times, done modifications and the only thing I'm getting is to move down or up the white gap. I've modified the template and put some stock content so you can check the source code.

Here is a codepen to check the source code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEoxKy

```
<div class="col num6" style="max-width: 320px;min-width: 250px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: top;background-color:#000000;">
            <div style="background-color: #000000; width: 100% !important;"><!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
            <div style="border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 5px;"><!--<![endif]-->
            <div align="center" class="img-container center  autowidth  fullwidth " style="padding-right: 0px;  padding-left: 0px;"><!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px;line-height:0px;"><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0.5px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="Image" class="center  autowidth  fullwidth" height="auto" src="https://www.demilked.com/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/5aaa1ce36b9c8-funny-weird-wtf-stock-photos-coverimage.jpg" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; clear: both; border: 0px; width: 261px; max-width: 245px; display: block !important;" title="Image" width="262.5" /> <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>

            <div align="center" class="img-container center  autowidth  " style="padding-right: 0px;  padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 5px; height: 40px;"><!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px;line-height:0px;"><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="Image" class="center  autowidth " height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/170x40" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; clear: both; border: 0px; width: 192px; max-width: 168px; display: block !important;" title="Image" width="192" /> <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>

            <div><!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td height="80" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;background-color:#000000;"><![endif]-->
            <div class="bwmxstext" style="color:#998b70;line-height:150%;font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <div style="font-size:12px;line-height:18px;color:#fff;font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;text-align:left;height: 80px;">
            <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 12px;line-height: 18px;text-align: center"><span style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 25px;"><strong><span style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 13px;">LOREM IPSUM</span></strong></span></p>

            <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 11px;line-height: 16px;text-align: center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum dictum sollicitudin. Donec mattis mauris et massa dapibus, at posuere neque mollis.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>

            <div align="center" class="img-container center  autowidth  " style="padding-right: 0px;  padding-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px;line-height:0px;background-color:#000000;"><td width="25%" align="right"><img src="https://www.nubiscrm.es/lists/images/image/testAgosto/boton-left.png"></td><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; background-color: #fff; vertical-align: middle;" width="50%" valign="middle" align="center"><![endif]--><a href="#" style="background-color: #fff; padding: 3px 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 13px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BOOK NOW&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> <!--[if mso]></td><td width="25%" align="left"><img src="https://www.nubiscrm.es/lists/images/image/testAgosto/boton-right.png"></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>
            <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div>
            <!--<![endif]--></div>
            </div>
```

This is how it's seen on Outlook 2010. I can't find any element causing that white gap. Also tried to set the main container to black so maybe I could hide it but it's not getting the color at all.

[image: Problem]

Comment: Your outlook conditional statements have heights. Tried giving the td's in the conditional statement a background color?

Comment: Yes I did, that's the strangest thing... It didn't do anything. It just appears at the third position. If I clone that container and add below the other one, it still appears at the third one, but not at the last one.

Comment: Maybe you have your code too long and outlook is causing a page break. Break the big table into two at that point and try. I saw something like this in Litmus and Email on Acid sometime ago.

Comment: Exactly, seems like Outlook it's breaking the page at the third table he finds. Because If I break that nested table that makes the content look good, the white gap will go for the next table, which is found in the footer. This is a huge problem to deal, specially with a black background...